# Как после переустановки сохранить данные в sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Я сохраняю `id` пользователя в sharedpreferences и после переустановки приложения `id` пользователя стирается. Как сохранить данные в sharedpreferences, так чтобы после переустановки sharedpreferences помнил данные?

Comment: не думали об альтернативе в виде SQLite?

Comment: по вашему мнению это наилучший вариант ?

Comment: sharedpreferences подразумевает запись в файл, если этот файл удалить с СД карты - или переустановить приложение, то он будет удален, и это никак не предотвратить. Далее здесь была написана простыня по поводу SQLite, но задумался и понял, что не уверен в его поведении, и задался вопросом - а БД разве сохраняется?Короче сам сижу думаю теперь.

Comment: но могу сказать однозначно, если у вас есть сервер на котором можно хранить айдишники- то это будет определенно лучшим вариантом, и решаться будет через SQLite.
Насчет SharedPreferences можете попробовать написать костыль, который будет записывать в txt файл нужные вам данные, и не зависеть от того, установлено ли ваше приложение. Обновлять при помощи перезаписи. Но это конечно сами понимаете, решение не самое лучшее.

Comment: зачем, вообще, сохранять `id`? как Вы его потом используете?

Comment: я работаю над игрой при входе в приложение создается id пользователя и к нему привязывается вся инфа пользователя . есть и другие способы но пробовал этот вариант на практике

Comment: при login происходит идентификация пользователя мне надо сделать идентификацию пользователя без login